# Scrollbar not tracking down when new content is added

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

```js
<div
            ref={forwardedRef}
            className={containerClasses}
            data-bubble-index={index}
          >
            {!myMsg && bubble.fromDisplayName && (
              <div className="mr-2">
                <AvatarPhoto
                  name={bubble.fromDisplayName}
                  size="sm"
                  src={bubbleParticipant.avatarUrl}
                />
              </div>
            )}
            <div className={bubbleContainerClasses}>
              {!sameFrom && !myMsg && (
                <span className="text-sm text-gray-400">
                  {myMsg ? 'me' : bubble.fromDisplayName}{' '}
                  {bubbleParticipant?.roleLabel &&
                    `(${bubbleParticipant?.roleLabel})`}
                </span>
              )}
              <div className="w-full">
                {bubble.message?.match(url_pattern) ? (
                  <span
                    className={bubbleClasses}
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                      __html: replaceUrlsWithAnchors(bubble.message),
                    }}
                  />
                ) : (
                  <span className={bubbleClasses}>{bubble.message}</span>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
```

Scroll bar does not track down when a long paragraph is input.
The scrollbar should go all the way down and stay down as the user sends messages.

This is the parent div and the chat feed div:

```
     <div className="flex flex-col justify-between h-full" data-cy="chatThread">
          <div className="sticky top-0 bg-primaryBg">
            <SidePanelHeader onDismiss={handleChatToggle} alignChildren="left">
              <button className="flex items-center pl-2" onClick={showActiveChats}>
                <span className="mr-1">
                  <Icon svg={LeftArrow} size={10} color="accentText" />
                </span>
                Back to All chats
              </button>
            </SidePanelHeader>
            <ChatGroups
              chatId={chatId}
              isMyParty={isMyParty}
              isTeamMeeting={meeting?.type?.key === 'team-meeting'}
              chatGroupParties={chatGroupParties}
              dmParticipant={dmParticipant ? dmParticipant[0] : undefined}
            />
          </div>
     </div>
```

```
      {/* Chat Feed*/}
          <div
            className={classNames('flex flex-auto flex-col overflow-y-auto p-3', {
              'bg-red-100': !isMyParty && meeting?.type?.key !== 'team-meeting',
            })}
            data-cy="chatThread-feed"
          >
            {mergedMessagesAndParticipantsInThread().map((chatBubble, index) => (
              <ChatBubble
                participants={allParticipantsFlat}
                prevBubble={getMessages()[index - 1]}
                bubble={chatBubble}
                index={index}
                key={chatBubble.ts}
                ref={scrollToRef}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
```

Here is a screenshot of the scroll bar not tracking down when a large block of text is entered.

[image: An image showing the scroll bar not tracking down when a large block of text is entered.]

The `scrollIntoView` is working now, but if I scroll to the top of the chat box it will take me back to the top of the last message once the component re-renders. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vM0KG.png)

```
    const scrollToRef = (node: HTMLElement | null) => {
        if (node !== null) {
          const refIndex = Number(node?.dataset?.bubbleIndex) + 1;
          const ref = document.querySelector(`[data-bubble-index="${refIndex}"]`);
          if (ref && ref.getBoundingClientRect().top > 0) {
            ref.scrollIntoView({
              behavior: 'auto',
              block: 'start',
            });
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: I'm assuming that you're using the `scrollToRef` somewhere to scroll to the bottom, perhaps by using `scrollIntoView()`. Could you include that code in your question?

Comment: The scrollIntoView is working just fine now. The only issue I have remaining is when the components re-renders it takes me to the last sent message. That's wrong... Can a useEffect() handle this?

Comment: Can you add the code that's calling your `scrollToRef()` function?

Comment: The scrollToRef() is passed down to ChatBubble as ref(prop) inside of ChatBubble they pass the `forwardRef` type and you can see the rest with snippet up top.

Comment: fixed the scroll bar going back to the last sent message by using setting state to false once the message is sent.